# Show the following limit does not exist

Tags: analysis, limits

Let $f,g$ be two functions of two variables, which satisfies that:

i) $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous of degree $n$,

ii) $g(1,1)\neq0$ and $g(1,0)\neq0$,

iii) $g(1,1)*f(1,0)\neq f(1,1)*g(1,0)$.

Show that $Lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ does not exist.

I have been trying to proof it by Reductio ad absurdum but none of my attempts have solved the exercise.

Any hint what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=a x^2+b y^2+c x y$ and $g(x,y)=d x^2+e y^2+f x y.$

If $\;L=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac {f(x,y)}{g(x,y)}$ exists then $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {f(x,0)}{g(x,0)}=\frac {a}{d}=\frac {f(1,0)}{g(1,0)}$$ and also $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {f(x,x)}{g(x,x)}=\frac {a+b+c}{d+e+f}=\frac {f(1,1)}{g(1,1)}.$$ But then $$L=\frac {f(1,0)}{g(1,0)}=\frac {f(1,1)}{g(1,1)}$$ implying $f(1,0) g(1,1)=g(1,0) f(1,1).$